# My background image not appears in my site

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to use an image as background in my code, but the image does not appear, i just got a white background

```css
body{  
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(88, 0, 185, 1), rgba(40, 0, 255, 0.5)), url(components/images/bgheader.svg);   
  font-family: MADE TOMMY THIN;   
  font-size: 16px;   
  line-height: 20px;   
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px; 
  color: white; 
}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT3k9.png)

Comment: Could you try with only background, instead of background-image?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work

Comment: You need to use double quote with url("components/images/bgheader.svg");

Comment: Any errors in network tab? 404?

Comment: @Mehdi I tested without double quotes and it worked just fine. I still think its a good practice but it seems like its not required

Comment: @mehdi quotes in url are not required if the string doesn’t have eg spaces.

Comment: Please give a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The code you have given won’t show anything because the body has no height.

Comment: @A Haworth didn't know that always seen it with quotes so good to know that. Thanks for correcting

Comment: @Steffen GET file:///C:/Users/Davi/Documents/c%C3%B3digos/.yourlp/styles/components/images/bgheader.svg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @DaviCastaldini The path is wrong, so you're getting a 404. Your components folder is not inside your styles folder, I assume.